# Is the memory limit affected when running multiple instances of Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I can run multiple instances of Matlab by simply opening the program multiple times. An instance of Matlab has a [memory limit](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/memory.html).

If I open two Matlab programs on my computer, will this limit be affected and how? E.g. will it be split in two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I observe, the memory limit per instance is calculated dynamically based on the actual available RAM. For instance, we run one instance per thread on a 12 thread CPU (and 64GB of RAM) and never had problems with lacking memory.

I did a simple test:

1. Run first matlab instance and use the `memory` command to get memory information:

   > > memory
   > >     Maximum possible array:        7651 MB (8.023e+09 bytes)
   > >     Memory available for all arrays:        7651 MB (8.023e+09 bytes)
   > >     Memory used by MATLAB:        2268 MB (2.378e+09 bytes)
   > >     Physical Memory (RAM):       16263 MB (1.705e+10 bytes)
2. Open the second instance and use the `memory`command in both instances shows, that the available memory decreased in the first instance and is nearly the same as in the second instance.
3. Open some other programs which use some memory and use the `memory` command in both instances shows again, that the available memory decreases.
4. Creating some huge variables in one or both instances also reduces the memory in each instance.

I hope this answer helps, although it is more experimental.